# pipe flow boundaries in cartesian coordinates

Tags: c++, pipe, pde

I am trying to solve the Navier-Stokes equations in Cartesian coordinates with Finite Element Model. I investigate Rheolef c++ library for this purpose. I understand the applied the variational formulation.
I can't declare the boundaries of pipe flow.
I appreciate any help!

I expect to formulate the circle boundary in C++

Comment: _"I can't declare the boundaries of pipe flow"_ - If you show a [mre] of  how you tried implement it and also describe the problem in detail it'll be easier to help - especially for someone like me who knows nothing about the domain (expressing the Navier-Stokes Equations in Cartesian Coordinates) at all.